# Rails how to set date and time for 2 days ahead at 4pm (in different zone) (Rails, Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I need to set different date/time for tests in my Rails app, namely:

- in 2 days from now at 7am: is it Time.zone.today+2.at(7,0,0) ?

I used http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/ to get the `Time.zone.today` but I can't find anywhere how to say in 2 days from now at at CERTAIN time

Answer (score 8):

I would use [`from_now`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-from_now) to generate an instance of Time with the time set 2 days in the future and then use [`change`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Time.html#method-i-change) to set the time to 7am:

```
2.days.from_now.change(hour: 7)
```

Comment: thanks but i need to keep .zone in order to say to Rails that the time i input must be this time in each time zone. could i write 2.days.from_now.zone.change(hour: 7) ?

Comment: `2.days.from_now` is based on `Time.zone.now`. Therefore the zone should be correct.